# Combining mouse buttons and keybord keys for hotkeys

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, mouse, virtualdesktop

Question is about mouse buttons customization.
 I want ctrl, alt, shift to modify my mouse buttons behavior on being pressed.

My mouse have 9 buttons, prev, next buttons in it already working.
 I would like to configure my ubuntu to have:

- ctrl + prev mouse button = change virtual desktop to left
- ctrl + next mouse button = change virtual desktop to right

Does such combinations possible to configure on Ubuntu or other OS?
If yes then how hard it will be?
I have also one unused mouse button, is there any trigger like iterate next through workspaces?

I am doing a lot o this switches. To do so, I move my hand a lot between keyboard and mouse. It slows me down pretty much. Answer to my questions and any alternative solution would be great.

Minor solutions:

- setting hotkeys that can be managed just by left hand, (super - s in unity shows workspaces)
- dedicating mouse buttons to do just it
- using trackpoint on the keyboard - less hand movements

Answer (score 0):

I use [Easystroke](http://easystroke.sourceforge.net/) to control mouse button behavior, you can probably set it up to do this.